# Should string literals be placed in code tags?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if there is a general policy on if string literals should be in code blocks or not. IE "Hello World" vs `"Hello Word"`. I've noticed that in some questions people do it and in some they don't, and of course in some its half and half.

This is particularly useful in regex questions, where you often deal mainly with a single string literal. IE [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171993/substring-in-unix) question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely. Using code tags for string literals makes it clearer what things are data being computed upon and which are just some kind of special wording (sometimes known as "jargon").

It's also sometimes easier to discern characters in the code font -- smart quotes, for example: `“”`, which can cause a certain amount of trouble when substituted for straight quotes: `""`.